# How to loop in informatica until a RESTful service does not have any more info?

Tags: rest, informatica

With Infomatica, I need to loop on a RESTful service until there is no more XML data to return.  The RESTful service has a parameter call "Page" which you increment until there is no more information.  For example, "http://bogus.com?Page=0" would be the first call.  Next call would be "http://bogus.com?Page=1"...  etc.  Eventually the service would respond back with just "" which indicates the end of the data.   How do I create a loop in Infomatica that can do this?